# How to modify a nested list tree structure in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, tree

I have parsed some JSON data from a reddit commments section. I am trying to get the comment structure represented as a nested list (tree) of the authors who made the comments. My input data would look something like this:

```
[u'a1',
 [u'a2',
  [u'a1', [u'a2']],
  u'a3',
  [u'a1']],
 u'a4',
 [u'a5']]
```

In this example, a1 and a4 are the child nodes of the original parent post. a1 has two children associated with it, a2 and a3. a4 only has one child node (one response). I believe the structure I actually want should be like this:

```
[[u'a1',
  [u'a2',
   [u'a1', [u'a2']]],
  [u'a3',
   [u'a1']]],
 [u'a4',
  [u'a5']]]
```

Here is a focus on how I would like the first item to be reformatted:

```
[u'a1',
  [u'a2',
   [u'a1', [u'a2']]],
  [u'a3',
   [u'a1']]]
```

I am pretty lost, but I had something like this to reformat the tree at only level right below the parent node:

```
[tree[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(tree),2)]
```

I need something like this that will work recursively, and can deal with an arbitrary number of child nodes to a parent. I am super stuck.

Thanks

Comment: You should really consider a better way of storing your data...

Comment: This is extremely niche. For example, how would you specify the criteria for modification? There is no one-fits all. It's not even a binary tree, the elements aren't unique.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I need something like this that will work recursively

Iterate recursivly over a nested `list` of `list`, for instance:

```
_list = [[u'a1',
  [u'a2',
   [u'a1', [u'a2']]],
  [u'a3',
   [u'a1']]],
 [u'a4',
  [u'a5']]]

def scan(_list, l=-1, i=-1):
    if isinstance(_list, list):
        print('list {}:{}'.format((l,i), _list))
        l += 1
        for i, item in enumerate(_list):
            scan(item, l, i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scan(_list)
    print('3,1:{}'.format(_list[0][1][1][1]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> list (-1, -1):[['a1', ['a2', ['a1', ['a2']]], ['a3', ['a1']]], ['a4', ['a5']]]
> list (0, 0):['a1', ['a2', ['a1', ['a2']]], ['a3', ['a1']]]
> list (1, 1):['a2', ['a1', ['a2']]]
> list (2, 1):['a1', ['a2']]
> list (3, 1):['a2']
> list (1, 2):['a3', ['a1']]
> list (2, 1):['a1']
> list (0, 1):['a4', ['a5']]
> list (1, 1):['a5']
> 3,1:['a2']
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***